# Leaflet js overlayadd / overlayremove - How to check for more than one layer?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am rather new to javascript and I'm trying to get my project to run. The goal is to show several overlays conditionally - so if Layer1 and Layer2 are both added (checked out by a user in the checkbox), a LayerControl should be run.

Also: If one of them is removed, the control should be completely removed from the map.

I have a problem at checking if both layers are added at the same time. The && (AND) as well as || (OR) are not working for me. 
Here the example of my code:

```
map1.on({
overlayadd: function(e1,e2) {
    if (e1.name === 'LAYER1'&& e2.name==='LAYER2'){
    sBs01 = L.control.sideBySide(LAYER1,LAYER2);
    sBs01.addTo(map1);
    }
},
overlayremove: function(e) {
    if (e.name === 'LAYER1'|| e.name==='LAYER2') {
    map1.removeControl(sBs01)
    }
}});
```

This should be rather simple but I guess I'm missing something.

I also tryed it in another way, to avoid AND/OR, by adding IF two times, like this:

```
map1.on('overlayadd', function(eventlayer){ 
    if (eventlayer.layer==LAYER1) {
        map1.on('overlayadd', function (eventlayer2)
        {
            if(eventlayer2.layer==LAYER2){
            sBs01 = L.control.sideBySide(LAYER1,LAYER2);
            sBs01.addTo(this);
            }    
        }       )
        } } );
```

It does the work but not optimally. The broblems appear when trying to remove the control later, if any of the 2 layers is removed.

Please help me with this issue with your inputs, it will mean a world to me!

Answer (score 2):

You're using the `overlayadd`/`overlayremove` events, which only work when a layer is added/removed *through a `L.Control.Layers`*. This might cause problems if the layers are being added/removed through other means.

I suggest you use the `layeradd`/`layerremove` events (see http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.0.html#map-event ), and check against instances of `L.Layer` instead of their names in a layers control.

Also, due the nature of events you'll only get the reference (name or instance) to the layer affected by that event. You're writing `overlayadd: function(e1,e2) {`, but there's no way that an event handler function will receive two events at once (see http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.0.html#evented-on ), much less in the order you expect.

If you want to check combinations of layers added to (or absent from) the map, use `L.Map`'s `hasLayer()` instead. See http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.0.html#map-haslayer.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you very much for your answer and useful inputs, @IvanSanchez!

All layers were added through `L.Control.Layers`, so `overlayadd` and `overlayremove` did work for them. I did however used  `hasLayer()` in checking the conditions regarding layers and it worked :)

Something like this worked:

```
sBs01 = L.control.sideBySide(LAYER1,LAYER2);
    map.on('overlayadd', function(eventlayer){ 
        if(eventlayer.layer===LAYER1){
        if(map.hasLayer(LAYER1)){
            sBs1.addTo(this); 
            }});
```

And analog to this, for overlayremove.
It may help someone.